# A proof that there is an angle $\theta$ such that cos($\theta$) = $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

Would anyone be willing to provide and explain a geometric proof that there is an angle $\theta$ such that cos($\theta$) = $\theta$

I came across it in a textbook, but I have trouble understanding it.

Comment: Put $\theta = 0$ and then $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Draw pictures. Use continuity

Comment: Graph $y = x$ and $y = \cos x$

Comment: $\cos(p)$ is the x coordinate of the angle $p$, cos starts out at 1 for p=0 and at p=pi/2 it is 0. Since both cos(p) and p are smooth there must be a value in between where they cross.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(\theta) = \cos \theta - \theta$.

Then $f$ is clearly continuous, and $f(0) = 1 > 0$ while $f(5) < 0$.
By the intermediate value theorem, there is a point in the middle where $f(\theta) = 0$. At that point we necessarily have $\cos \theta = \theta$.

Comment: The OP asks about a geometric proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x) = cosx - x$$
Then$$f'(x) = -(sinx + 1)$$

$\sin(x)$ never attains a value less than -1, so $f'(x)$ is always negative or zero, hence the function is strictly decreasing.

$$f(0) = cos(0)-0 =1$$

$$f(\pi)= cos(\pi) - \pi = -(1+\pi)$$

Hence ONE root must exist between $(0,\pi)$. AND no other roots exists as f(x) will always be negative as it is STRICTLY decreasing.

and $f(x)$ is continuous on REAL